Interpolate and Clip Concave Boundary Data for 3D Surface Plots in Python
I am working on a project where I need to create a 3D surface plot. The dataset "x y z color" is in a non uniform grid.

Additionally, I have a separate file containing a set of points that form the left boundary of the surface.
I am trying to interpolate the surface data within this boundary and plot it in 3D. However, I am struggling with correctly interpolating the data to conform to the concave shape of the boundary and excluding data outside this area.

Here is the data for the boundary
0.5000011312772511  0.9999503225071016  0.010000442395794491    0.005
0.500001140089003   0.9998002675422002  0.020003885702647665    0.01
0.5000011798112299  0.999550025819314   0.030013333831617344    0.015
0.5000012880768092  0.9991993719317389  0.04003179670142108 0.02
0.5000015177307953  0.9987479898351447  0.05006229325944634 0.025
0.5000019369886614  0.9981954723749855  0.0601078545158198  0.03
0.5000026296433487  0.99754132067445    0.07017152661573131 0.035
0.5000036953188669  0.9967849433839776  0.08025637392316401 0.04
0.5000052497752266  0.9959256557902396  0.09036548217238696 0.045
0.5000074252622885  0.9949626787843852  0.10050196163782579 0.05
0.50001037092775    0.9938951376862389  0.11066895034826003 0.055
0.5000142532806519  0.9927220609188651  0.1208696174503791  0.06
0.5000192567121552  0.9914423785382339  0.13110716646585244 0.065
0.5000255840757588  0.9900549206052752  0.14138483880658953 0.07
0.5000334573344162  0.988558415409107   0.15170591725634755 0.075
0.5000431182722865  0.9869514875231834  0.1620737295921134  0.08
0.5000548292798774  0.9852326557027417  0.1724916522825041  0.085
0.5000688742149383  0.9834003306119743  0.1829631143141833  0.09
0.500085559345211   0.9814528123825679  0.1934916011003794  0.095
0.5001052143776197  0.9793882879909978  0.20408065857909385 0.1
0.5001281935810702  0.9772048284473063  0.21473389738046406 0.105
0.5001548770105084  0.9749003858220506  0.22545499720357498 0.11
0.5001856718379002  0.9724727900384286  0.23624771129161323 0.115
0.5002210138008032  0.9699197454999648  0.24711587112097785 0.12
0.5002613687769464  0.9672388274922852  0.25806339128651706 0.125
0.5003072344956199  0.9644274783732285  0.2690942745497424  0.13
0.5003591423985235  0.9614830035591169  0.28021261710569323 0.135
0.5004176596613754  0.9584025672581398  0.2914226140959445  0.14
0.5004833913919013  0.9551831879700036  0.30272856539803655 0.145
0.500556983020396   0.951821733801294   0.3141348815354828  0.15
0.5006391229012028  0.9483149173990695  0.3256460900918845  0.155
0.500730545142759   0.9446592907928485  0.33726684218940073 0.16
0.5008320326920536  0.940851239827587   0.34900191947516196 0.165
0.500944420695111   0.9368869784045428  0.3608562413853676  0.17
0.5010686001648622  0.9327625423973618  0.37283487275017296 0.175
0.5012055219830495  0.928473783303336   0.3849430317611802  0.18
0.5013562012767159  0.9240163615818817  0.39718609850015574 0.185
0.5015217222030115  0.9193857396872898  0.40956962380599543 0.19
0.5017032431923294  0.9145771747822609  0.4220993386567344  0.195
0.501902002694183   0.9095857111687172  0.43478116401354083 0.2
0.502119325487346   0.9044061723537689  0.44762122137807864 0.205
0.5023566296137947  0.8990331528041908  0.4606258437802666  0.21
0.5026154340122538  0.8934610093820474  0.4738015875578159  0.215
0.5028973669323259  0.8876838524725617  0.487155244591037   0.22
0.5032041752214875  0.8816955367253859  0.5006938556171434  0.225
0.503537734593336   0.8754896515619643  0.5144247239954818  0.23
0.5039000610005778  0.8690595113277488  0.5283554306160175  0.235
0.5042933232495755  0.8623981451554441  0.5424938495011189  0.24
0.5047198570189394  0.8554982865920885  0.5568481645646254  0.245
0.505182180467757   0.8483523629991662  0.571426887368682   0.25
0.5056830116471486  0.8409524846489255  0.5862388759594233  0.255
0.5062252879618473  0.8332904338346913  0.6012933551917243  0.26
0.5068121879699291  0.8253576537523871  0.6165999381272089  0.265
0.5074471558569453  0.8171452374200945  0.6321686488743842  0.27
0.5081339289719434  0.8086439166972035  0.6480099473788276  0.275
0.5088765688896839  0.7998440514298645  0.664134755469705   0.28
0.5096794965298042  0.7907356190107414  0.6805544849433707  0.285
0.5105475319783913  0.7813082043538541  0.697281067723305   0.29
0.5114859397561708  0.7715509906409421  0.7143269878796238  0.295
0.512500480435574   0.7614527510047073  0.7317053165797631  0.3
0.5135974696698373  0.7510018414615505  0.7494297488503675  0.305
0.5147838459176807  0.740186195506984   0.7675146437743293  0.31
0.5160672484029836  0.7289933207357892  0.7859750673037237  0.315
0.5174561071761141  0.7174102981323879  0.8048268386720585  0.32
0.5189597475375545  0.7054237845375272  0.8240865801376177  0.325
0.520588511593822   0.6930200192335912  0.8437717710869546  0.33
0.5223539003403157  0.6801848354401041  0.8639008058846505  0.335
0.5242687404687704  0.6669036779648141  0.8844930569937796  0.34
0.5263473811110114  0.6531616283650671  0.9055689430871349  0.345
0.5286059270326668  0.6389434392782417  0.9271500026689459  0.35
0.5310625164900867  0.6242335800042101  0.949258974475845   0.355
0.5337376541491514  0.6090162958169182  0.9719198840753223  0.36
0.5366546123587664  0.593275684061104   0.9951581387880066  0.365
0.5398399179112119  0.5769957907657641  1.0190006305394426  0.37
0.5433239465414645  0.5601607324195828  1.0434758481846664  0.375
0.5471416543696762  0.542754848542136   1.0686140000559379  0.38
0.5513334849823286  0.5247628921916805  1.0944471479593683  0.385
0.555946503999085   0.5061702671604679  1.1210093538485488  0.39
0.5610358314137184  0.48696332291185224 1.1483368404733023  0.395
0.5666664682309694  0.4671297212804191  1.1764681678504938  0.4
0.5729156518012448  0.4466588925349565  1.2054444271037783  0.405
0.5798759299003311  0.4255426035576688  1.2353094540383123  0.41
0.587659226805283   0.4037756673954496  1.2661100644503391  0.415
0.5964023016218197  0.38135683243129664 1.2978963140511428  0.42
0.6062741973081358  0.35828990153063617 1.3307217862129004  0.425
0.6174865959370622  0.33458514865452355 1.3646439105978794  0.43
0.6303085174484443  0.31026112433532643 1.3997243169603169  0.435
0.6450876849760825  0.28534697660993835 1.4360292288480574  0.44
0.6622824390257734  0.25988546553037967 1.4736299021986068  0.445
0.6825109430619073  0.23393692932442386 1.5126031150400912  0.45
0.7066299291512341  0.2075845860056578  1.5530317156231248  0.455
0.7358664520942582  0.1809417628557541  1.595005236996346   0.46
0.7720505997414752  0.1541620087933328  1.6386205876967788  0.465
0.7803478711012877  0.14880678468070216 1.6475497697994446  0.466
0.7890619588121246  0.14345616115067164 1.6565496807482705  0.467
0.7982259432767803  0.13811225005513658 1.665621217339594   0.468
0.8078766455473015  0.13277730162988333 1.6747652913445186  0.469
0.8180551867790513  0.12745371512795517 1.6839828298942647  0.47
0.8288076532574393  0.12214405056999607 1.6932747758764743  0.471
0.8401858913443033  0.11685104176582206 1.7026420881087545  0.472
0.8522484634213099  0.1115776107989804  1.7120857417502302  0.473
0.8650618047847557  0.10632688420889695 1.721606728701647   0.474
0.878701633362084   0.1011022111057068  1.7312060579530748  0.475
0.893254680178963   0.09590718360247748 1.7408847558255638  0.476
0.9088208304564052  0.09074565990947925 1.7506438665467137  0.477
0.9255157956083957  0.085621790604625   1.760484452466698   0.478
0.9434744788921962  0.08054004868814157 1.7704075945912794  0.479
0.9628552579224899  0.07550526416668894 1.780414392920661   0.48
0.9838454943605606  0.07052266413378144 1.790505966798538   0.481
1.0066687089066437  0.06559791956668944 1.8006834555142062  0.482
1.0315940506140184  0.06073720042200571 1.8109480186202576  0.483
1.058948980531323   0.0559472411013757  1.8213008363738372  0.484
1.0891365431350983  0.05123541905570999 1.8317431102332167  0.485
1.1226593237110865  0.04660985025746674 1.842276063343787   0.486
1.160153380499215   0.04207950669941212 1.8529009409328063  0.487
1.2024374596138432  0.03765436317787694 1.863619010782999   0.488
1.2505863501420222  0.033345583841344124    1.8744315636500313  0.489
1.3060437398271136  0.02916576404673712 1.8853399136066773  0.49
1.3708024339438873  0.025129251356129784    1.8963453981062126  0.491
1.4477052429276849  0.0212525836145188  1.9074493777484796  0.492
1.5409752839578719  0.017555107349163778    1.9186532345311706  0.493
1.6572158061090254  0.014059887989824724    1.9299583672804796  0.494
1.8074656435341185  0.010795122763222214    1.9413661760516001  0.495
2.011943167544061   0.007796493207890757    1.952878008300029   0.496
2.3129488558303493  0.005111482675285709    1.9644949197594892  0.497
2.8202249897828557  0.0028085468814210922   1.9762161255682387  0.498
3.9708933572086713  0.0010021701642300709   1.9880169544472097  0.499

Here is the code I am currently using
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

# Read data
def read_data(file_name):
    return pd.read_csv(file_name, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, names=['x', 'y', 'z', 'color'])

# Read the surface data
data = read_data('3dplot.dat')

# Prepare points for Delaunay triangulation
points = data[['x', 'y']].values

# Create a Delaunay triangulation
tri = Delaunay(points)

# Extract vertices and create lists for triangles
i, j, k = tri.simplices[:, 0], tri.simplices[:, 1], tri.simplices[:, 2]

# Custom color scale definition
custom_colorscale = [
    [0, "#6446af"],  # Start color
    [0.5, "#818aa3"],  # Middle color
    [1, "#c5dca0"],  # End color
]

# Create a 3D mesh plot
fig = go.Figure()

# Add the surface plot
fig.add_trace(go.Mesh3d(
    x=data['x'], y=data['y'], z=data['z'],
    i=i, j=j, k=k,
    intensity=data['color'],
    colorscale=custom_colorscale,
    colorbar=dict(
        title='Φ<sub>H</sub>',
        tickfont=dict(size=14, family='Times New Roman'),
        x=0.9,  
        len=0.75, 
        thickness=25  
    ),
    name='Surface',
    opacity=1.  
))

# Layout
fig.update_layout(
    title='Data',
    width=800,  # Width of the figure in pixels
    height=600,  # Height of the figure in pixels
    scene=dict(
        xaxis_title=dict(text=r'X', font=dict(size=16, family='serif')),
        yaxis_title='Y',
        zaxis_title='Z',
        xaxis=dict(
            showbackground=True, backgroundcolor="white", gridcolor="black", title=dict(font=dict(size=16, family='serif')), 
            showline=True, linecolor="black", linewidth=1, showspikes=False,
            range=[data['x'].min(), data['x'].max()]  
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            showbackground=True, backgroundcolor="white", gridcolor="black", title=dict(font=dict(size=16, family='serif')), 
            showline=True, linecolor="black", linewidth=1, showspikes=False,
            range=[0, data['y'].max()]  
        ),
        zaxis=dict(
            showbackground=True, backgroundcolor="white", gridcolor="black", title=dict(font=dict(size=16, family='serif')), 
            showline=True, linecolor="black", linewidth=1, showspikes=False,
            range=[data['z'].min(), data['z'].max()]  # Define the range
        ),
        aspectmode='manual',
        aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=0.7), 
    ),
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=0)  
)

# Gridline properties
fig.update_scenes(
    xaxis_showgrid=True, 
    yaxis_showgrid=True, 
    zaxis_showgrid=True, 
    xaxis_gridwidth=1, 
    yaxis_gridwidth=1, 
    zaxis_gridwidth=1,
)

# Show the figure
fig.show()



Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
